# Removing encryption from recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, encryption

I'm running CyanogenMod 12 nightly on my G900T (klte). Everything works great except for the default encryption password, which causes my phone to boot loop.

I've formatted data and done factory resets, but `/data` is still encrypted and shows up as `/dev/dm-0`.

Is there a command that I can do to remove the encryption? I don't care about the data, I want it all gone. I just want to get back to having `/data` and the internal storage being stored in plaintext on disk to be able to boot into CyanogenMod.

How can I use `adb shell` to remove the encryption on these partitions?

Comment: Which recovery did you flash?

Comment: Team Win Recovery Project (TWRP)

Comment: I did read [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/96183-factory-reset-remove-encryption/) that you can get rid of the encryption by flashing a new ROM, not sure if that works in your case but it is worth a try.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm trying to manually `dd if=/dev/zero` and then format the data partition.

Answer (score 14):

The answer for me involved a number of things, but I think one is really the key.

## Use the "recovery" Command, bro

This uses CyanogenMod's/AOSP's `recovery` program to wipe the user data and disable encryption. (found in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829600/128967)) Boot into your recovery, and then from your computer run

```
adb shell recovery --wipe_data --set_filesystem_encryption=off
```

Your phone will reboot into system and things should hopefully work as planned.

If you need to run it from the phone itself (ie: you don't have a computer nearby to `adb` with):

```
recovery --wipe_data --set_filesystem_encryption=off
```

It should wipe, disable encryption, and reboot system.

## If All Else Fails

Don't use this method unless the above doesn't work or apply to your scenario.

#### Destroy the LUKS Header for Filesystem Encryption

1. You need a recovery which will allow you to drop to a shell as `root`, so TWRP works in my case.
2. Locate the `userdata` partition by looking around in `/dev/block/platform/*/by-name/userdata`.
3. Write out a ton of zeroes to the beginning of that partition to wipe the LUKS header:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=$PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA bs=4096 count=512
   ```

   I claim no responsibility for what you do with this command. If you screw this up, you can brick your phone by overwriting your bootloader or other critical partitions. Make sure that `$PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA` points to the real `userdata` partition. Check the size of that partition to make sure you're wiping the right thing. I have a 16GB phone and `userdata` is 10.4GB, with the rest being dedicated to `system`, but your phone will be different.
4. Reformat that partition as `ext4` using `make_ext4fs $PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA`.

   There might be errors, but usually they relate to not being able to find the internal "sdcard," this is okay.

After all this, reboot recovery again and then run a factory reset just to be safe.

#### Why Does This Work?

Simply doing a factory reset seemed to not do anything for me, the phone would still see a LUKS partition there. I assume that this is because the LUKS header still existed at the disk level and the ext4 partition was just overlaid on top of it. For some reason, Android prioritized detection of a LUKS partition over an ext4 partition and attempts (and succeeds) to mount that.

#### Where to Go from Here

(If you know what you're doing, you might also want to wipe `system` and install your ROM from scratch. *Again, I take no responsibility for anything you do with the information contained in this post.*)

Worked for me on a `klte` G900T (Samsung Galaxy S5 T-Mobile). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: That kind of worked (the dd / make_ext4fs option).  -- When I rebooted, it still asked for a password in TWRP recovery, and the advanced format options didn't work -- but when I did a regular data partition format, it worked. -- I was able to reboot into recovery without any prompts for passwords. :-)

Comment: Naftuli, you are a lifesaver! I've got my S6 edge (SM-G925F) in dead boot loop, as it was not able to encrypt probably because of custom recovery (TWRP), I think encryption is made via stock recovery. It was keep saying "encryption was not finished. factory reset and reboot". I even tried to flash stock recovery, it didn't boot (probably wrong one but labeled for my device). Whole stock rom was not good either (was not able to find proper one, that one I found was rejected by odin). Finally I did everything you said here, and `dd` command finally did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `recovery` command didn't seem to work for me. I called it from `ADB Shell` in `TWRP` recovery.

My main issue is that USB debugging isn't enabled and `/system` is corrupted so I can't boot and enable it.

Also, disk encryption is on and seems to keep me from performing `fastboot flash system system.zip` correctly.

Comment: You saved my day, or better my night. After three hours trying to install lineageOS 14.1 on my Huawei P8 Lite and getting always the encryption unsuccessful message, with the `dd` command in the end I could conclude the operation. Thank you!

Comment: `ls -l /dev/block/platform/soc.0/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata` says: 
`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root         root                21 Sep 16 06:04 /dev/block/platform/soc.0/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p26`
`df -h /dev/block/mmcblk0p26` says:
```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26
                         10.5G     27.2M     10.5G   0% /data`
```

so I did: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/soc.0/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata bs=4096 count=512`

Is that right?

Comment: (Part 2): `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/soc.0/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata bs=4096 count=512`

gives me:
```
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
2097152 bytes (2.0MB) copied, 0.003430 seconds, 583.1MB/s
```

I am wondering, why does it say that only 2MB where copied?

Comment: I still get the error: `E: unable to wipe '/data' -- unknown file system 'auto' Unable to format to remove encryption` on my Honor 5x

Comment: `make_ext4fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p26`says: 
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 11614007296
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8160
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label:
    Blocks: 2835451
    Block groups: 87
    Reserved block group size: 695
Created filesystem with 11/709920 inodes and 84285/2835451 blocks

Answer (score 11):

On my Moto G 3rd Gen (osprey), neither calling recovery nor wiping LUKS header (at start and end of partition) worked - I still needed to enter the encryption password during Cyanogen Mod bootup, then was stuck with an "encryption error" message.

I finally found that my TWRP 3.0.1 recovery has a "Format Data" option in the "Wipe" section. This does a complete factory reset which also disables encryption.

Worked like a charm. If you have access to a decent TWRP version (easily flashed e.g. with Flashify), try this first.

Comment: Thank you. Why go for a complicated solution when a simple one will work?

Comment: My only problem with that option was that the text implies it will also wipe your SD card. If your card is easy to get to, then that's not much of a problem. :-|

Comment: @pgmann: 'format data' option appeared not long ago in TWRP, that's why. For sure it wasn't there in 2014 when those replies were provided. Also, the `dd` approach is useful when cleaning encryption in scripts, as 'format data' option is not available in TWRP commands, while existing commands can't wipe encryption. Hope they add such command in future...

Answer (score 5):

**Provided that you're using TWRP or similar.**

- reboot to TWRP (enter password), and make a backup of `Data` partition to external `SD` or `OTG Drive`
- reboot to TWRP (cancel password), and format Data partition to `f2fs`
- restore backup made in step one to newly created `Data` partition
- reboot system
- enjoy Android with all your data saved, and encryption removed

Answer (score 4):

The solution of manually wiping the LUKS header provided by Naftuli Tzvi Kay works fine, except for one thing. I do not how what it depends on, but in my experience, Android keeps the LUKS header at the END of the partition. And if that is the case with your device, then running

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=$PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA bs=4096 count=512
```

will fail to remove the header (footer?) because it wipes only the beginning of the partition. 
One could of course wipe the entire partition, but that would take unnecessarily long. So...

**To wipe the end of the partition** (of any size), after running the above command, run this command also:

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=$PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA count=22048 seek=$((`blockdev --getsz $PATH_TO_YOUR_USERDATA` - 22048))
```

Comment: wiping only header worked OK for me (may be because encryption was not finished - not sure). But upvoting your answer because of your low karma ))

Answer (score 4):

## Are you using custom recovery?

If yes, then do this after booting to a custom recovery (**TWRP** in my case):

1. On recovery start, **DO NOT decrypt the device**. Just tap **Cancel** when asked of password or pattern.
2. **Wipe the data partition.** (On TWRP after swiping to modify system: Wipe > Advanced > Check: Data)

This will of course wipe everything in the `userdata` partition. The whole data partition will be reformatted **including the encryption keys**.

Comment: Wiping the data partition simply removes the filesystem header at the beginning of the partition. It doesn't work because on many versions of Android, the LUKS/dm-crypt header is at the _end_ of the filesystem.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it just worked in my Nexus 9.

Comment: not sure why somebody downvoted this answer,  this works, and is the simplest way to get rid of encryption

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - and it worked. :)

Comment: Same here. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me, using TWRP 3.2.3 on an i9100 (Galaxy S2). The key is choosing Cancel instead of providing Recovery with the decryption password. Then options to remove data encryption magically appear in the Wipe menu.

Comment: On my device the key was stored in `metadata` partition, see [this article](https://jsteward.moe/analysis-of-android-cryptfs.html)

Answer (score 1):

My votes go to @Naftuli Kay, and other helpful answer here, but I have some info I'd like to share. It's too long for a comment, let it be an answer then.

Since some version of TWRP, there's 'format data' item on Wipe screen. It not only wipes /data partition, but also handles the encrypted FS matter. In my case, TWRP 3.0.2 on Samsung J500H wipes encryption, and it was the only way, factory reset doesn't work. CMR (that one being built along my CM 12.1 rom for J500H) can't clear encryption either.

`--set_encrypted_filesystem=off` also didn't work in TWRP and CMR.

wiping data via OpenRecoveryScript https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html also doesn't work

Android 3.0 started to map /sdcard to /data/media, so they had to rework /data wipe to not /data/media, and `rm -rf` is performed instead. See https://twrp.me/faq/datamedia.html for more details.

When you perform 'format data' you may see in recovery log (/cache/recover/log or /cache/recovery/last_log) following info:

```
I:Successfully wiped crypto footer.
```

before it formats /data with `make_ext4fs`. The TWRP code has number of checks to find where the LUKS header is, and in my case it found it in the footer.

I looked at the TWRP source and I haven't found a way to 'format data' from command line (I need to wipe encrypted storage from an application in custom rom), so this option is present in UI only. With the only exception - if TWRP is compiled with `TW_OEM_BUILD` enabled then it **will** 'format data' on factory reset, clearing crypto header and formatting data partition, otherwise it would use regular wipe w/o formatting.

I'm going to try to `dd` with zeros, actually TWRP does the same to clear encryption, just it knows where to look for the header exactly ))

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Naftuli Tzvi Kay's answer above...

well, that answer got me to the right place, but my phone (CM11 / i9300) didn't have a `recovery` command, and the `wipe` command didn't have an option to disable encryption. So I did it manually from looking at the comments in [the source code for the `recovery` command](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_bootable_recovery/blob/cm-10.2/recovery.c) (file linked from the answer linked in the above question):

```
* The recovery tool communicates with the main system through /cache files.
* /cache/recovery/command - INPUT - command line for tool, one arg per line
* /cache/recovery/log - OUTPUT - combined log file from recovery run(s)
* /cache/recovery/intent - OUTPUT - intent that was passed in
*
* The arguments which may be supplied in the recovery.command file:
* --send_intent=anystring - write the text out to recovery.intent
* --update_package=path - verify install an OTA package file
* --wipe_data - erase user data (and cache), then reboot
* --wipe_cache - wipe cache (but not user data), then reboot
* --set_encrypted_filesystem=on|off - enables / diasables encrypted fs
*
* After completing, we remove /cache/recovery/command and reboot.
```

So to do it manually (with adb):

1. get up a prompt with root access, e.g.

   > ```
   > $ adb shell
   > > su
   > ```
2. put the following text into the file /cache/recovery/command, either with echo or vi:

   > ```
   > --wipe_data
   > --set_encrypted_filesystem=off
   > ```
   >
   > e.g. with `echo -e "--wipe_data\n--set_encrypted_filesystem=off" > /cache/recovery/command`
3. reboot into CWM or similar recovery

You should see a nice progress bar and it should get done :)

Comment: recovery command is available in my TWRP (3.1.1), it accepts --wipe-data and --set_encrypted_filesystem=off both via /cache/recovery/command or command line, but as soon as access to data partition is requested (by --wipe-data) TWRP prompts for password. So it doesn't work in latest TWRP. 'Format data' works instead, see other posts

Answer (score 0):

The best working method is to boot into TWRP and use the inbuilt terminal to format it as ext2(coz that's the only thing supported from terminal directly), and change the partition to ext4 using the "Repair Filesystem" Option under Mount

**To format as ext2:**

`mkfs.ext2 /dev/block/mmcbl0p23` (Substitute with the value of your userdata partition by looking around in /dev/block/platform/*/by-name/userdata )

**Change filesystem as ext4:**

Wipe -> Advanced Wipe -> Select "Data" ->Repair or Change FileSystem -> Change File System -> EXT4

Now, you should have encryption removed, and be able to mount /data partition from TWRP. Hope this helps :)