# Analyzing boot loop Root cause from console-ramoops-0 ( & logcat)

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, logging

**Summary - Update 2:** 
I am not deleting the question content, to preserve history ( but an admin may if appropriate delete that content)  but things have change since. A day after I can into the below mentioned `TWRP createTarFork() error 255` issue I could manage the data restore `/data` from `TWRP Nandroid backup`. **The issue is for 2nd install of the same `stock ROM`  - I run into a `bootloop`.** The `TWRP backup` itself was from an `Encrypted partition`  being restored to another `partition` ( `Encrypted` or otherwise regardless ). Trying to get to the RC of the `bootloop` & some way I an restore my `/data` I've attached logs of bad & normal boot below.

this is older history. *May go directly to update 1 below ,* skipping  it :
`Boot-looped` and got stuck in powered by android logo. `Logcat` hasnt been much useful. Wanna know what's causing the stuck.
All I have is this from `/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0`

```
'android.frameworks.sensorservice@1.0::ISensorManager/default': No such file or directory
```

I am attaching [Entire  /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0](https://paste.c-net.org/GranddadBronze)

what seems the issue ?
 I have TWRP backups of `vendor system boot` that i tinkered restores with. No Luck. This is stock `MIUI ROM` with `TWRP as recovery base` so after flashing dm-verify-no encrypt.zip ( cant recall the exact name ) + certification.zi & permssiver I  get past `MIUI` logo but now looping at powered by `android` logo

`fsck` outcomes

```
    olivelite:/ # e2fsck /dev/block/mmcblk0p60
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p60: clean, 4614/65536 files, 184349/262144 blocks
olivelite:/ # fsck /dev/block/mmcblk0p60
/sbin/sh: fsck: not found
127|olivelite:/ # e2fsck -v /dev/block/mmcblk0p60
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p60: clean, 4614/65536 files, 184349/262144 blocks
olivelite:/ # e2fsck -v /dev/block/mmcblk0p59
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p59: clean, 4547/262144 files, 680379/1048576 blocks
olivelite:/ # e2fsck -v /dev/block/mmcblk0p62
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
data: clean, 62826/1389536 files, 3383723/5667584 blocks
olivelite:/ # e2fsck -v /dev/block/mmcblk0p57
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p57: clean, 33/98304 files, 22707/98304 blocksenter
```

`fsck` sounds clean for all `partitions` 
[Here is the `**logcat**`](https://paste.c-net.org/RopesSchemes) & [here's `**dmesg**`](https://paste.c-net.org/RubbleStacey)
from `logcat` it could be a `decryption` issue. But that's only for `boot`
`twrp`asks for pattern and decrypts just fine. Why cant it happen during `boot`- that's my hunch on the prob. Not trying to lure  in that direction. Like *Mikko* said pretty much everything  screams so its difficult to nab the culprit 
 Gonna try  `/data` backup `wipe` and `restore` lets see...
.
**Update**
as I suspected it appears to be `encryption` related. the previous successful install had  a `pattern lock`  ( at the time that install was built, I `flashed - permissiver.zip, certificate.zip & dm-verity-force-encryption w default ops to disable verity &  disable forced encryption`  )  - but`TWRP nandroid backup` itself is never `encrypted`. When  tried to restore it - I always ended up with `TWRP createTarFork() error 255` which is a very  generic error - with multiple RC's. In my case it happens immediately ( previous data was `wiped & formatted all relevant partitions` . Only way I could successfully restore was use `flashtool` ( that runs `fastboot` commands underneath ) to install `stock` ->  `fastboot twrp & patched magisk boot  install` and then restore `/data` ( after running `magisk` &  `dm verity` attempt `twrp` restore ) - in that case restore was successful. So with above steps I could successfully restore `/data` but that restored `/data` will get stuck in `bootloop` ( if `twrp` backups arent `encrypted` , why then does a simple `wipe & format` not allow `TWRP restore` ? only `flashtool` de-novo `stock` install will permit restore ? . I read a bug in `twrp` will not let backup from `encrypted  partition` be restored onto un-encrypted ..ok so I also `encrypted` de-novo `stock` install with same pattern & after successfully restoring `/data` got stuck in the same `bootloop` again  ) . 
 while I am using this de-novo `stock` install right now with 'bare minimal survival kit' apps.
I could pull up logs of what a `successful boot` looked like
to compare with `boot loop after /data restored` I uploaded earlier ( as suggested by  *Mikko* - need bad boot and normal boot logs to compare ) . 
 **So the big Question** 
 is how in the world can I get back `/data` to restore from my `Nandroid backup` without `boot looping`
Uploaded these : 
Normal boot [`pmsg-ramoops`](https://paste.c-net.org/MethodsMovement) , [`dmesg`](https://paste.c-net.org/KeeganEmpress),  [`ramoops`](https://paste.c-net.org/FeelsCostanza) ( last 2 are pretty much the same - if you read ramoops- good enough ), [`logcat`](https://paste.c-net.org/DeformedOverture)
Needless to say restore's being attempted on the same stock ROM

Comment: Universal Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt.zip still has [bug](https://github.com/Zackptg5/Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt/issues/12) and will cause boot-loop on encrypted data (although not related to twrp bug restoring failure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues  & solutions much as I could reach** 
Cant restore `TWRP /data backup`
Can't figure out why `TWRP` backup itself being un-`encrypted` ( albeit from an encrypted phone ) cant be restored to any phone with the same ROM. This is with `TWRP 3.5.x`. Work around was flash ROM de-novo ( `wipe / format` in TWRP did not work ) &  then attempt restore. But I ran into `bootloop`.  There is another  [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98228/removing-encryption-from-recovery)  that targets `Luks Header` , but did not bother going further down the rabbit hole.
 I really appreciate Mikko's dig into those logs , which is understandably is boring and frustrating .much as I'd have like to accept his answer - it's way off. This is abs nothing to do with `SeLinux`( `permissive 1` as the `log`  shouts everywhere ) neither it was a corrupted fs ( `e2fsck`  issue)

`Bootloop`  after `/data restore` 
Something to do with my older install being `encrypted` but I cant figure out presicely. I took my  TWRP files and attempted manual restore :

```
$r --selinux --xattrs -vxpPf data.ext4.win003 /data/data/com.whatsapp
```

where r is `/data/tmp/tar-arm` as [suggested here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214065/backup-whatsapp-from-nandroid) . My `whatsapp` data ( primary  target of recovery besides other apps  ) was straddled across 03 an 04 volumes and I ran into issues `invalid tar format` or some. The issue was not with backup but `/data/tmp/tar-arm`wasn't capable . I pulled it into `Linux` and ran  regular tar similarly and restored. Lesson : if `tar` utils says  backup is bad - dont take it for-granted. It might be a bad `tar`

Comment: Note that it is *not safe* to use ROM that doesn't have SELinux enabled as your daily driver. It sounds that the ROM you're trying to use is just broken or if `/data/tmp/tar-arm` wasn't provided by the ROM, that's the problematic part of your adventure. If you have encrypted data partition, you have to use good enough TWRP version or you cannot actually have a working backup (it's easy to notice - if you have encrypted data partition, TWRP should prompt for password). Note that the backups made with TWRP *are not encrypted*; see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188339/5738 for details.

Comment: Howdy Mikko `SeLinux 1` is kept so state in many `Custom ROM`s . In my case for stock `ROM` I keep it at 1 momentarily to see where all did I violate & accordingly change context before toggling but that is at ease  . `/data/tmp/tar-arm` isnt expected as per what the link mentioned - you have to grab it from the smallest available `gapp`. Still dont follow why 1) that `/data` restore `boot-looped` 2) UnEncry'd backup from `Encry Part`cant be restored simply & causes `Tar Fork` found that as a bug report in an older `TWRP` version & this is few hoops ahead

Comment: thanks Alec ..actually `busybox tar`  as well as `arm tar` both were tried and they both threw up in the middle of  the road so as to say. If it was a problem of wrongly using it - they'd not extract partially . Entire f would be  rejected w something like 'not a tar archive' --this error was unexpected end of `tar`. AFA `UUID`s are concerned.  Yes I did that by a program I wrote that grabbed individual `UID & GID` after the `apks` got installed and run `chown` but that wasnt part of Q I asked. I will nonetheless put in an udpdate line for completeness

Comment: Well *bad* might be a 'bad' name after all. It should at least be able to list out the contents vide `tf` option and that is just where it gives that  error as welll . And on `Linux` it worked just fine no issues. So I guess the *bad* was reference to its incompatibility with my `tar`. AFAIK when I made that `tar` using `TWRP` I never used the compress option.  I grabbed an `ARM tar` based on the link choosing the smallest package size...should have delved into it being available solo ...

Comment: so you say the malformed header is not caused by twrp-tar on creating, and the error output (which is filtered with `2> /dev/null` in linked question) does only appear on arm but not on x86? that's strange because I always get it. what is your linux tar version, is it [star](http://s-tar.sf.net) maybe (because that's what twrp-tar is based on)?

Comment: here's my Linux Pup  `tar` `root# tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
`

Comment: `gnu tar`  admittedly `secontext` isnt something that worried me cos my `SeLinux` is passive....not Good, yes I know. But keeping it like that till I find all the  raves and rants in logcat about violations ... that is for future :)... the way I hv things ..I still use a 2nd `ext4` to store all my non split `apks` & all user app data ( save for his  TWRP backup sit'n). I wrote code that installs these `apks` & then finds out their `userid gids` & then links the data & does all necessary `chowns` the access rights were already there. Most apps work OOTB. Seldom complaints cos of diff. arch etc

Comment: so it's the same tar that behaves differently on arm

Comment: dunno could be? I will ..gimme s'time ... pastbin that entire comparison reproduce the error... if it'd help dig up the root

Comment: it took me ages to figure out why jellybean backup solution didn't work any longer. selinux was introduced with KitKat (permissive) and the only reason for me to compile gnu tar. if you copy app data with no secontext, restorecon will set (wrong) default values. but there is more, some xattrs are also important and will cause crashes even on permissive. if you follow instructions exactly it should work for you too (at least for WhatsApp)

Comment: btw there is [app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763&page=80) doing the same thing (restore app data and chown uids)

Answer (score 2):

If you run stock firmware and it's bootlooping, there's really not much that you can do because you don't have source code to the firmware you're running.

Your boot log seems to have a couple of interesting parts. I think this might suggest some kind of permission problem. Have you touched SELinux stuff (e.g. changed ACLs)?

```
[    0.629174] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.629189] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at /home/work/olivelite-p-stable-build/kernel/msm-4.9/drivers/base/core.c:600 device_create_file+0x7c/0xac
[    0.629193] Attribute otg_status: write permission without 'store'
[    0.629197] Modules linked in:
[    0.629205] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.9.112-perf-gd9f74a7 #1
[    0.629209] Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SDM439 (Flattened Device Tree)
[    0.629226] [<c0113194>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c010dbc0>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    0.629235] [<c010dbc0>] (show_stack) from [<c04e791c>] (dump_stack+0x94/0xa8)
[    0.629245] [<c04e791c>] (dump_stack) from [<c012f760>] (__warn+0xf8/0x110)
[    0.629253] [<c012f760>] (__warn) from [<c012f7d0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x58/0x74)
[    0.629260] [<c012f7d0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c0761e24>] (device_create_file+0x7c/0xac)
[    0.629271] [<c0761e24>] (device_create_file) from [<c087ebc8>] (msm_otg_probe+0x1668/0x1c28)
[    0.629281] [<c087ebc8>] (msm_otg_probe) from [<c0769a10>] (platform_drv_probe+0x48/0xac)
[    0.629289] [<c0769a10>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0767860>] (driver_probe_device+0x244/0x2f0)
[    0.629297] [<c0767860>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c07679d4>] (__driver_attach+0xc8/0xcc)
[    0.629303] [<c07679d4>] (__driver_attach) from [<c07652dc>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x8c/0xd0)
[    0.629311] [<c07652dc>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c07670e0>] (driver_attach+0x2c/0x30)
[    0.629317] [<c07670e0>] (driver_attach) from [<c0766c70>] (bus_add_driver+0x1ac/0x224)
[    0.629324] [<c0766c70>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c0768768>] (driver_register+0x9c/0x120)
[    0.629331] [<c0768768>] (driver_register) from [<c0769974>] (__platform_driver_register+0x50/0x58)
[    0.629341] [<c0769974>] (__platform_driver_register) from [<c16473dc>] (msm_otg_driver_init+0x1c/0x20)
[    0.629350] [<c16473dc>] (msm_otg_driver_init) from [<c0101ccc>] (do_one_initcall+0x60/0x1a4)
[    0.629359] [<c0101ccc>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c1601070>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x1f4/0x2b0)
[    0.629369] [<c1601070>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c0f7fd4c>] (kernel_init+0x18/0x158)
[    0.629378] [<c0f7fd4c>] (kernel_init) from [<c0108a10>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x24)
[    0.629384] ---[ end trace 09e0ec112fb2ab2d ]---
...
[    3.606115] init: Couldn't load property file '/odm/default.prop': open() failed: Nk such file or directory: No such file or directory
[    3.606592] selinux: avc:  denied  { set } for  scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:exported_secure_prop:s0 tclass=property_service permissive=1
...
[    5.976174] e2fsck: e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
[    5.976174] 
[    5.976210] e2fsck: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist is mounted.
[    5.976210] 
[    5.976222] e2fsck: e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
...
[    7.388219] type=1400 audit(54437781.749:20): avc: denied { setattr } for pid=404 comm="init" name="shared" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=1157358 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.399091] type=1400 audit(54437781.749:20): avc: denied { setattr } for pid=404 comm="init" name="shared" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=1157358 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.399114] type=1400 audit(54437781.759:21): avc: denied { setattr } for pid=404 comm="init" name="tombstones" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=514055 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.402174] type=1400 audit(54437781.759:21): avc: denied { setattr } for pid=404 comm="init" name="tombstones" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=514055 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file8s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.402193] type=1400 audit(54437781.769:22): avc: denied { write } for pid=404 comm="init" name="misc" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=385537 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.402323] type=1400 audit(54437781.769:22): avc: denied { write } for pid=404 comm="init" name="misc" dev="mmcblk0p62" ino=385537 scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[    7.402339] type=1400 audit(54437781.769:23): avc: denied { add_name } for pid=404 comm="init" name="dts" scontext=u:r:vendor_init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
```

Also note the `e2fsck` aborting in the middle of the process.

**I would guess SELinux config being messed up or a filesystem corruption.**

You'd really need a log from *correctly booting* phone with the *identical firmware version* to compare to know for sure. In many cases official vendor firmware is a piece of crap that may emit all the above errors on every boot so you really cannot know if you're looking at red herring.

Usually the only good way to debug issues like this is to take full boot log from known working phone and compare it to full boot log from a phone that doesn't boot. (Obviously you need a comparision tool that can ignore the timestamps at the start of the lines. I'd use `meld` with filters.)

**Usually the problem is caused by the first error in the log.** However, as I mentioned, **vendor firmware often have lots of errors on every boot** so you cannot know which are fatal if you don't have known good boot log to compare. The line you mentioned in the question (`ISensorManager/default`) is way after all the above mentioned errors. I would assume that the `ISensorManager` failure is just a result of the other stuff going wrong.

Comment: Your boot log also had some random bytes intermixed with the text. The first random byte appears in the middle of timestamp on line `This means that this is a DEBUG kernel`.

Comment: Yes it a `debug kernel` log it actually says so somewhere in the beginning. I am going to attach `dmesg` & `logcat` & Update the question. Thanks SO much for peeping in . BTW I ran `permissiver`  ( `flashed` )  script. So By the time it was boot and dandy -  `Selinux was permissivve`